# django sending email not show up in inbox

Tags: django, sendmail

I am sending email with django with company local host address. When I get data from form and send them, it shows up in terminal, but not being received in inbox. I checked both company and gmail emails,result is same.

```
#settings
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' 
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = '---'
    EMAIL_HOST_USERNAME = ''
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
    EMAIL_PORT = 25
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

## view

```
def contact(request):
    title = "Content"
    form = contactForm(request.POST or None)

    context = {'title': title, 'form': form,}

    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']

        subject = "Thanks"
        message = "%s %s" % (comment, name)
        emailTo = [form.cleaned_data['email']]
        emailFrom = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        send_mail(
              subject,
              message,
              emailFrom,
              emailTo,
              fail_silently=False,
        )
        title = "Thanks"
        confirm_message = "Thanks for the message. We will get right back to you."

    template = "contact.html"
    return render(request,template,context)
```

## inTerminal

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [08/Feb/2017 07:53:13] "POST /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7666
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Subject: #subject
    From: #host address
    To: #receiver address
    Date: Wed, 08 Feb 2017 07:53:20 -0000
    Message-ID: <-----.----.---- @natiq-macbook-pro.local>

    # Message
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Edit - Traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner


39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django2/src/contact/views.py" in contact
  29.                   fail_silently=False,

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  62.     return mail.send()

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  342.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  100.             new_conn_created = self.open()

File "/Users/natigvahabov/Desktop/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in open
  58.             self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in __init__
  256.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in connect
  316.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in _get_socket
  291.         return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py" in create_connection
  575.         raise err

Exception Type: error at /contact/
Exception Value: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: That is the point of the `console.EmailBackend`: the email is being sent to the console, not anywhere else! That's why you use it during development for debugging purposes only. How would an actual email be sent without any mail server settings?

Comment: Thanks, but when I update code with:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
I receive error that can be found in EDIT

Comment: Did you specified EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD  and EMAIL_HOST_USER?

Comment: If you are using Gmail , then you need to do some setting in Gmail. check "turn on " here (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

Comment: I'm using company host server, which username and password are null

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to following this configuration if you want to work with smtp gmail.

**Add this configurations in your `settings.py`**

> This configurations is if you work with `smtp.gmail.com`, other smtp is similiar with configurations.

1. Unlock the Captha: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
2. Change to active: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

---

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your_gmail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your_password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```